# Full Calendar looping infinite datesSet React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the month and year when I click on the FullCalendar library Toolbar, using "datesSet" to identify where the user is according to the page render. How can I fix this error below?

It is returning this error. It seems that the DataSet is returning an infinite loop. How can I fix this?

Error:
`Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

```
import { AdaptableCard, CalendarView } from "components/shared";
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";




const Calendario = (props) => {
  const [eventosComite] = useState([]);
  const [dados, setData] = useState({
    start: "",
    end: "",
  });

  const onDatesChange = useCallback(
    (arg) => {
      const { start, end } = arg;

      setData({
        start: start,
        end: end,
      });
    },
    [setData]
  );

  console.log(dados);

  return (
    <AdaptableCard className="h-full mb-5" bodyClass="h-full">
      <div className="lg:flex items-center justify-between mb-4">
        <h3 className="mb-4 lg:mb-0">Calendário</h3>
      </div>

      <CalendarView
        editable
        selectable
        events={eventosComite}
        datesSet={onDatesChange}
      />
    </AdaptableCard>
  );
};

export default Calendario;
```

Versions lib:

`````
 "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.4",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.4",
    "@fullcalendar/moment": "^6.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.4",
    ````
`````

Comment: Are you using this to try and refresh the events in the calendar? If so, that could cause the loop, because adding new events to the calendar can cause the view to refresh, which might then cause datesSet to occur again. This is not the approach you're supposed to use to create a dynamic event feed. Your options for that are discussed [in the documentation about event sources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source) . The JSON feed is simplest to implement, but you can also use the custom callback function if you need a more bespoke connection to your event data's source.